# Windows batch: forfiles output filenames with weird characters

Tags: batch-file, filenames, codepages

I'm trying to run a script on a 2008 Server which invokes a batch file with the following parameters:

```
forfiles -p %log_dir% -s -m *.* -d -3 /C "cmd /c echo @path" > %cfg_dir%\Filelist.txt"
```

My issue is that the output that is being written to a file, whenever the filename has non-ASCII characters (such as `é`, `ç`, `ã`), it is written with the wrong characters, example:

The file found is

```
S:\FOLDER\SUBFOLDER\0_Certi**dão** Predial.pdf
```

and it's written to the output file as

```
"S:\FOLDER\SUBFOLDER\0_Certi**d¦o** Predial.pdf"
```

I've already changed the charset to 850 (it was 470) but the output still comes out the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('chcp') do set src_cp=%%a

chcp 65001 & rem or chcp 1212

forfiles -p %log_dir% -s -m *.* -d -3 /C "cmd /c echo @path" > %cfg_dir%\Filelist.txt"

chcp %src_cp%
```

Comment: the above code breaks i'm not sure where, but you did gave me a great help.
I included the line 
chcp 65001 before the forfiles command i wrote before and it worked. thanks again.

Comment: @ biocoma by the way I think your language is portuguese, you can check [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb490874.aspx). codepage _65001_ is UTF-8